# Where should I ask about how to resolve my game crashing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, asking-questions

I have a game that has a launcher (i.e. modded [Minecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft), legacy [*Feed the Beast* launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTB)), and it crashes some time after I launch one of the modpacks. Where should I ask for support?

To clarify, the game *is not* crashing my computer and showing a blue screen, but it exits itself and shows me a log. It throws me a NullPointerException in Java.

I am not asking about game development, but rather about using a game, so it is definitely not gamedev.se.

Comment: Did you consider [SE Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I considered that, but I don't think I should since Arqade is usually about the game itself.

Comment: Arqade doesn't take questions about modded minecraft

Comment: Looks like you can't solve it unless it's reprogrammed, so you have to ask the place where you got the mod from.

Comment: I have tried it, and I haven't got an answer for two days, so I thought maybe someone will answer it if I posted it on SE.

Comment: Arqade meta dupe: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13559/153006

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, modded Minecraft is off-topic everywhere.  Arqade only accepts questions about un-modified Minecraft, while video games in general are off-topic on Super User.